# MongoDB Query does not return Complete data after creating index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB Colllection which has following data

```
> db.UpdateQueryRegistry.find({"studyId" : "20130117193010cfab"})

{  "_id":ObjectId("50f95af799ac247d280484dc"),
   "attempts":0,
   "eTime": ISODate("2013-01-17T17:03:36.501Z"),
   "lastUpdDt": ISODate("2013-01-18T14:23:51.141Z"),
   "numQueries":1,
   "query":"Q1",
   "sTime":null,
   "start":0,
   "status":"COMPLETED",
   "studyId":"20130117193010cfab",
   "updateAction":"convertToIUorNO",
   "updateSource":"DOCUMENTSTATUS"
}
{ "_id":ObjectId("50f95af799ac247d280484db"),
   "attempts":0,
   "eTime": ISODate("2013-01-17T19:50:34.392Z"),
   "lastUpdDt": ISODate("2013-01-18T14:23:51.141Z"),
   "numQueries":1,
   "query":"Q2",
   "sTime":null,
   "start":0,
   "status":"COMPLETED",
   "studyId":"20130117193010cfab",
   "updateAction":"instanceAddQuery",
   "updateSource":"ONTOLOGY"
}
{ "_id":ObjectId("50f95af799ac247d280484da"),
   "studyId":"20130117193010cfab",
   "updateSource":"ONTOLOGY",
   "updateAction":"instanceDeleteQuery",
   "query":"Q3",
   "sTime":null,
   "eTime":null,
   "status":"PENDING",
   "numQueries":0,
   "lastUpdDt": ISODate("2013-01-18T14:23:51.141Z"),
   "attempts":0,
   "start":0
}
```

The index is created on DB as follows:

```
> db.UpdateQueryRegistry.stats().indexSizes

{
    "_id_" : 8176,
    "studyId_1_status_1" : 24528,
    "studyId_1_updateSource_1_updateAction_1_query_1" : 98112
}
```

But when I fire query

```
db.UpdateQueryRegistry.find({
    "studyId" : "20130117193010cfab",
    "updateSource" : "ONTOLOGY",
    "updateAction" : "instanceDeleteQuery"
})
```

I do not get any results but when I fire query

```
db.UpdateQueryRegistry.find({
    "studyId" : "20130117193010cfab"
})
```

I see 3 results displayed above. Please tell me if there is any error in this.

Comment: Try to execute `db.UpdateQueryRegistry.getIndexes()` to gather more information about your indexes.

Comment: A similar case happened to me once I created a sparse index. Later I understood that the index was corrupted and removing and creating the index again solved the problem.

Comment: One issue here is the field on which index is created contains data more than 1024 bytes. Will this cause indexing / querying to fail?

Comment: Can you run an explain on the failing query and paste the output?
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/optimization/#use-explain-to-evaluate-performance